# Trouble with Flask's request.is_secure using gunicorn and heroku with Flask

Tags: heroku, flask, gunicorn

I've seen this problem discussed on the web, but the explanations for fixing it aren't exactly clear, especially if you're not super familiar with Flask.  It's the issue where request.is_secure always returns False when flask is running on gunicorn on Heroku, even if the request is done with HTTPS.  I'm using Flask 0.8 and gunicorn 19.0.0.

I found [this](https://gist.github.com/allanlei/5754495) link, makes it look like you create a file called gunicorn.py with those contents, but that just created an import error on the Heroku server.  Then I tried taking those settings and applying them directly to my `app` Flask object by doing:

```
app.secure_proxy_ssl_header = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
app.forwarded_allow_ips = '*'
app.x_forwarded_for_header = 'X-FORWARDED-FOR'
app.secure_scheme_headers = {
'X-FORWARDED-PROTO': 'https',
}
```

but still no dice.  Can somebody please give a clear explanation of what I have to do, and where to put the configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out the solution was much simpler than I thought.  All I had to do was:

`from werkzeug.contrib.fixers import ProxyFix`

and then

`app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(application.wsgi_app)`

Comment: Should it be `ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app)` instead of `ProxyFix(application.wsgi_app)`?

Comment: In recent versions of werkzeug, `ProxyFix` is in `werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix` instead of `werkzeug.contrib.fixers`.

Answer (score 2):

I know you already fixed your problem, but I had a similar issue and had to set a second RequestHeader in Apache:

```
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
  RequestHeader set X-Scheme https
  Timeout 300
  ProxyTimeout 300
```

And that seemed to work.